# GET AND JOIN two data from two different table for If conditions PHP

Tags: php, database, date

I have two tables

table A (result a view from some table) :
Query from table A :

> SELECT  view_person_schedule.*, view_history_absen.*, TIMEDIFF(time_in,schedule_time_in)  AS late, TIMEDIFF(schedule_time_out,time_out) as overtime FROM person JOIN view_history_absen ON view_history_absen.ID = view_person_schedule.ID

table A :

> **ID  |  dates       |  time_in  |  time_out  |**
>   1   |  2014-06-01  |  07:00    |  ........  |
>   1   |  2014-06-02  |  08:00    |  ........  |
>   1   |  2014-06-03  |  08:10    |  ........  |
>   1   |  2014-06-04  |  .....    |  ........  |
>   1   |  2014-06-05  |  .....    |  ........  |
>   1   |  2014-06-10  |  .....    |  ........  |
>   1   |  2014-06-14  |  .....    |  ........  |

table B :

> **ID  |  dates_exc   |  information  |**
>   1   |  2014-06-06  |  NULL         |
>   1   |  2014-06-07  |  NULL         |
>   1   |  2014-06-08  |  NULL         |
>   1   |  2014-06-09  |  NULL         |
>   1   |  2014-06-11  |  SICK         |
>   1   |  2014-06-12  |  SICK         |
>   1   |  2014-06-13  |  SICK         |

My question is : how to make result data to be like this below :

> **ID  |  dates       |  time_in  |  time_out  |**
>   1   |  2014-06-01  |  07:00    |  ........  |
>   1   |  2014-06-02  |  08:00    |  ........  |
>   1   |  2014-06-03  |  08:10    |  ........  |
>   1   |  2014-06-04  |  .....    |  ........  |
>   1   |  2014-06-05  |  .....    |  ........  |
>   1   |  2014-06-06  |  NULL     |  ........  |
>   1   |  2014-06-07  |  NULL     |  ........  |
>   1   |  2014-06-08  |  NULL     |  ........  |
>   1   |  2014-06-09  |  NULL     |  ........  |
>   1   |  2014-06-10  |  .....    |  ........  |
>   1   |  2014-06-11  |  SICK     |  ........  |
>   1   |  2014-06-12  |  SICK     |  ........  |
>   1   |  2014-06-13  |  SICK     |  ........  |
>   1   |  2014-06-14  |  .....    |  ........  |

Please anyone help me.

Comment: What happens if both tables have a row for the same date?

Comment: Barmar, can u tell me more about ur question?

Comment: If `Table A` and `Table B` both have a row for the same date, what should be in the result? Just the row from one table (which?), or both rows?

Comment: i'll keep show data on table B

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are no overlapping dates in the two tables, or you want both rows in the result when there are, use a `UNION`:

```
SELECT id, dates, time_in, time_out
FROM TableA
UNION
SELECT id, dates_exc, information, NULL
FROM TableB
```

If Table B should take precedence when there's overlap:

```
SELECT dates.id, dates.dates, IFNULL(b.information, a.time_in) AS time_in, a.time_out
FROM (SELECT id, dates
      FROM tableA
      UNION DISTINCT
      SELECT id, dates
      FROM tableB) AS dates
LEFT JOIN tableB AS b ON dates.id = b.id AND dates.dates = b.dates
LEFT JOIN tableA AS a ON dates.id = a.id AND dates.dates = a.dates
```

Comment: but, how if use select * ?? not spesific field.
and table A is generate/result form some tables (thats as view)

Comment: Why would you ever want to use `SELECT *` when you can select the specific fields that you need?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use `SELECT *` when you're combining data from tables with different numbers of columns. Both subqueries in a `UNION` have to have the same number of columns.

Comment: Barmar, thank you for ur attention before, so i mst use spesific selected field?

But, how about if i has query like above from table A?

Comment: Unless you're doing a union of tables that have very similar schemas. They have to have the same number of columns, and the columns must match up. It's not usually a good idea to depend on this, because it means you can't modify the tables any time after you write an application like this.